# Richfaces 4.3.3 meets which JSF standard?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

I'm relatively new to JSF and Richfaces so this may seem an odd question to ask but I will explain why I am asking it also.

Firstly could someone tell me to which JSF standard Richfaces meets? All I see on the Richfaces 4.3.3 website is that it meets JSF2 however there are versions 2.0, 2.1 and 2.2. Is Richfaces compatible with all those JSF2 standards as indicated here?

Now the reason I ask is because don't I have to specify which JSF version I am working to in `faces-config.xml`? e.g.

```
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
</faces-config>
```

This is to JSF2.0 standard and I could not use any CDI/Annotaions from JSF2.2 e.g. `@Inject'. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: The version is that of the _faces-config_ document format, not the JSF version. This has not changed in the version range 2.0-2.1 though other artifacts have such as the _facelet-taglib_ format. See the specifications [JSR 314](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=314) and [JSR 344](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=344).

Comment: Thanks McDowell. when I was experimenting I found that by changing the version number some of my JSF pages would not work correctly. I assumed the version number referred to the JSF spec because certain things stopped working when this was changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [Richfaces 4.3.X Developer Guide](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_3_X/Developer_Guide/en-US/html/chap-Developer_Guide-Getting_started_with_RichFaces.html#sect-Developer_Guide-Getting_started_with_RichFaces-Technical_Requirements), RichFaces 4.3.3 has mandatory third-party dependency **Java Server Faces 2.x implementation**

- javax.faces.jar (version 2.1.19 or higher)
- or myfaces-impl.jar (version 2.1.10 or higher)

Answer on question about `faces-config.xml` is in McDowell comment.
In RichFaces 4.3.3 you can use JSF 2.1 or CDI annotations.